# Aggregate all codetags in a single file

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to aggregate all code tags like in a single file. From

```
main.py
# TODO: write some function
# BUG: 'func asdf()' does not work

some.py
# TODO: define ports
# BUG: smth wrong
```

to

```
codetags.md
# TODO: write some function
# TODO: define ports 

# BUG: smth wrong
# BUG: this code does not wor
```

At [PEP 350 - Codetags](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0350/) i found a rotten link to some http://tracos.org/codetag progect. Maybe there are some other projects

Comment: What do you mean by aggregate? Have you started by extracting lines starting with `# TODO|PORT|BUG`?

Comment: @JonClements yes, tell me please how can I extract all lines starting with `# TODO|PORT|BUG` in a single file?

Comment: Open the file, iterate over the lines, and use `str.startswith` to check for what you want...

Comment: @JonClements thanks alot for this simple solution